# Wrap every instance of number in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to achieve something simple - I have a bunch of chemical formulas and I wish to wrap any numbers in the formulas with  tag, but I cannot see to get it to work.

What I have tried so far is: 
`formula.replace(/d/g, '<sub>$1<sub>')`
but that just replaces the digit with the string '$1' wrapped in a sub tag.

Comment: can you show us examples please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
    console.log("34 and 26".replace(/(\d+)/g, '<sub>$1<sub>'))
```

You can use group capture for that purpose.

\d is a digit class

+ means 1 or more occurence of the previous class

() parenthesis enable a group capture.

I suggest you have a look at how to use regular expressions

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Thank you, this works and you're right - should master them myself.

Comment: @jacobdo There is no need wrapping the whole pattern with a capturing group. Use `/\d+/g` and replace with `<sub>$&</sub>`